# Get total rows incorrect

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm using Firebird 2.5, here's the code:

```
SELECT r.RDB$RELATION_NAME AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_ROWS
FROM RDB$RELATIONS r
JOIN RDB$RELATION_FIELDS f ON r.RDB$RELATION_NAME = f.RDB$RELATION_NAME
GROUP BY r.RDB$RELATION_NAME;
```

There is a table called "customer", and above code returns total rows = 332 rows

If I run:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer;
```

the result returns total rows = 10000++ rows

What have I missed in the first SQL statement?

Comment: The first statement will return the count of columns in table. The second one will return count of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement returns the number of fields (columns) because
[RDB$RELATION_FIELDS](https://ib-aid.com/download/docs/firebird-language-reference-2.5/fblangref-appx04-relfields.html) stores the definitions of table and view columns.

The second returns the number of rows (the data).

As I understand you want to get the number of rows (data) in all tables. If so you can use:

[How to get record count for all tables?](https://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq376/):

> Sometimes, when inspecting a database, you might want to get a quick
> glance over all the tables to see which ones actually have some data
> in them. There is no quick and easy way to get rough estimates, but
> you can always run brute-force "select count(*)" query on each table.
> Combining EXECUTE STATEMENT and EXECUTE BLOCK you can do this in a
> single SQL command:
>
> ```
> set term !! ;
> EXECUTE BLOCK
> returns ( stm varchar(60), cnt integer )
> as
> BEGIN
> for select cast('select count(*) from "'||trim(r.RDB$RELATION_NAME)||'"' as varchar(60))
> from RDB$RELATIONS r
> where (r.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG is null or r.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0) and r.RDB$VIEW_BLR is null
> order by 1
> into :stm
> DO
> BEGIN
> execute statement :stm into :cnt;
> suspend;
> END
> END
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You're querying the metadata tables, which provides information on the structure and definition of database objects. The table `RDB$RELATIONS` contains the tables and views, and the table `RDB$RELATION_FIELDS` contains the definitions of the columns of tables and views.

If the first query returns 332 for `CUSTOMERS`, it means the table `CUSTOMERS` has 332 **columns**, it does not in any way reflect the number of rows that are stored in the table `CUSTOMERS`.